# tolower() segfault's when trying to assign the returned value a char pointer

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, string-literals, tolower

I'm trying to understand the black voodoo magic that are pointers and I can't get my head around the following cases.
My understanding of the first parameter of getline() is clumsy, so I guess it all comes down to its type, which is different from the word in the second example.

The following is an extract from a function that loads a file (a dictionary of words) and reads its content line by line. Why does tolower() work in this first example:

```
int l;
size_t len = 0;
char *word = NULL;

while ((l = getline(&word, &len, fp)) != -1)
{
    for (char *p = word; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
    // Irrelevant code below
}
```

But segfaults in this second example, right after trying to assign the return of tolower() from the first char:

```
char *word = "POTATO";
for (char *p = word; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
```

Comment: Incidentally, when the type of `p` is `char *`, use `tolower((unsigned char) *p)` rather than `tolower(*p)`. The C standard does not define the behavior of `tolower` when `*p` is negative but not `EOF`, and `char` values can be negative in some C implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It would be enough to look through the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Firstly, string literals are character arrays with the static storage duration.

That is for example in C the string literal `"POTATO"` has the type `char[7]`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "sizeof( \"POTATO\" ) = %zu\n", sizeof( "POTATO" ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( "POTATO" ) = 7
```

Used in expressions arrays with rare exceptions (as for example using as operands of the operator `sizeof`) are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So in this declaration

```
char *word = "POTATO";
```

that (only for a demonstrative purpose) can be rewritten like

```
char *word = &"POTATO"[0];
```

the string literal used as an initializer is converted to pointer to its first letter `'P'`.

To avoid such a mistake of changing string literals in C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays.

Thus in C++ you have to write

```
const char *word = "POTATO";
```

It is advisable to declare pointers to string literals in C also with the qualifier `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing my question I decided to recheck the getline() documentation.
According to it the first parameter is a char **lineptr. Meaning it's a pointer to a pointer to a char.
More specifically:

> getline() reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the
> buffer containing the text into *lineptr

Due to my still limited understanding of double pointers and pointers in general, I've decided to read the code for getline(), trying to understand what's going on:

https://dev.w3.org/libwww/Library/src/vms/getline.c

Here's what I've understood and my correction to the second example, so that it doesn't segfault.

```
char word[] = "POTATO";
for (char *p = word; *p; ++p) *p = tolower(*p);
```

Then trying to really understand why the correction has worked, I've also searched for the differences between char arrays and char pointers and I've found and read the following:

https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/character-array-and-character-pointer-in-c/

What I've learned is that elements of the array can be individually modified. But chars pointers (string literals) cannot.

I thought the latter could be done, but it's not possible. Hence my mistake in the second example.
I was trying to modify the values pointed to by a char pointer and got a segfault in return for my lack of Black Mojo understanding.

Now I understand a little better and the trip has been enjoyable.

Please feel free to edit or add your insights.